# DNX - how to use 3rd party library debugging symbols?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dnx

I'm using ASP.MVC 5. At this moment, documentation is still missing some important pieces, and I need to reverse-engineer some stuff.

I was able to download the sources, build it on my own with.

So, at this point, I have `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.6.0.0-rc1-final.symbols.nupkg`, with desired DLL and PDB.

Previously, I'd just replace the referenced DLLs in my website's /bin/ with the ones build in debug mode (and PDBs), and be all set.

I don't know where does the website live, so I cannot replace any DLLs. I assumed that somehow I can tell VS to use .symbols. package where appropriate, but no luck in finding that option.

Is there any feasible way how to have 3rd party library built in debug and actually debugged?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. unpack nupkg file (it's a zip file - just change extension) and extract .pdb files OR use ones from build (probably that's what you ment but just for documentatin purposes)
2. Use symbols window in VS to point to folder with symbols[image]
3. Instead of using pdb file use sources by editing global.json file (`projects` section) to add external project path like ([source site](http://bleedingnedge.com/2015/12/06/project-reference-asp-net-5/)):

`{
       "projects": [ "src", "test", "c:\\sources\\Configuration\\src" ],
       "sdk": {
         "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
       }
     }`